# Having trouble installing the japid module in play framework

Tags: playframework

I'm trying to install the **japid** module in play framework, but no success. I have installed japid-0.9.2.4 using `play install japid-0.9.2.4`. After that `play japid-gen` is supposed to be called in the application root but i don't know how to get this command done. Can anyone help me out ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in your dependencies.yml file

```
- play -> japid-0.9.2.4
```

Or, alternatively you can add this line in application.conf file

```
module.japid=${play.path}/modules/japid-0.9.2.4
```

Then, install the dependencies in your app

```
play dependencies appName --sync
```

Now you can run this command

```
play japid:gen appName
```

For more info on dependencies, http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/dependency